# Value конкатенирует значение

Tags: javascript

нужно чтобы было 5+5+5+5 а не 5555555, всмыле чтобы цыфры сложились а не стояли рядом друг с другом

```
<input type = "number" class = "text">
<button class = "btn">asdasd</button>

document.querySelector(".btn").onclick = function (){
document.querySelector(".text").value = document.querySelector(".text").value + 5 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Это происходит, потому что вы складываете строку (value) и число. Оберните `document.querySelector(".text").value` в `Number()` и все заработает.

```js
document.querySelector(".btn").onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector(".text").value = Number(document.querySelector(".text").value) + 5
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="text">
<button class="btn">+5</button>
```